# Ruby: What's the meaning of [var] << AnotherObj

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, operators

I'm working with a legacy Rails project and found a piece of code that don't understand.

Given that

```
 search = Sunspot.search(entities)
 ...
 [search] << AnotherClass.new
```

Obviously they are two different object type. What is the meaning of using `[] <<`

Comment: Sure, i know what is an array.

Comment: So you know that `[search] << AnotherClass.new` is equivalent to `item = AnotherClass.new; current_array = [search]; current_array.<<(item)`, and that the last command calls Array#<<, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<<` operator appends the object on the right to the array.

```
[search] << AnotherClass.new
```

Try this on the Rails console:

```
a = [1,2]
=> [1, 2]
>> a << 3  # appends 3 to the array
=> [1, 2, 3]

>> [6, 7] << 8  # appends 8 to the newly declared array on the left
=> [6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 4):

`[...]` is an Array literal, and `<<` is an operator on Array that means "append". It returns a new array with right-hand-element appended to the end. So:

```
[search] << AnotherClass.new  #  =>  [search, AnotherClass.new]
```